# How to aggregate data with filter on text fields in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Having read all the tutorials on ES website, I cannot achieve my goal.
We are using ES 1.7.6 and I want to have only one single instance of documents matching my criteria. But what I get from ES is all the data matching the filter and the aggregation statistics.

```
GET _search
{
   "size":1000,
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "should":[
            {
               "match":{
                  "isoMessage.fields.39":{
                     "query":"00"
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "aggs":{
      "group_by_CATI":{
         "terms":{
            "field":"isoMessage.fields.41"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Note that the index of `isoMessage.fields.41` is set to `not_analyzed`.
Thanks for any help;

> UPDATE: The mapping

```
{
    "cm": {
        "mappings": {
            "Event": {
                "properties": {
                    "deleted": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "id": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "isoMessage": {
                        "properties": {
                            "fields": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "2": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "3": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "4": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "7": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "11": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "12": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "13": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "14": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "22": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "25": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "32": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "37": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "39": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "41": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "42": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "48": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "49": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "60": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "63": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "100": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "128": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "isReversal": {
                                "type": "boolean"
                            },
                            "isReversalDone": {
                                "type": "boolean"
                            },
                            "messageSpec": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "mti": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "request": {
                                "type": "boolean"
                            },
                            "response": {
                                "type": "boolean"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "msg": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "occurDate": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "receiver": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "rrn": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "sender": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    },
                    "txId": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "version": {
                        "type": "long"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your mapping

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas please read the update.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, and you want to get only the aggregation result:

Change your `size` field from:

`"size":1000`

to

`"size":0`

in order to set the `_search` query displayed results limit. It won't affect the aggregation result, though.